# Zend\Db Model with Child Models

Tags: zend-framework2, parent-child, zend-db, one-to-one

ZF2 project - no Doctrine, using native Zend\Db: Have the following structure:

```
Controller 
    ProductController
Model
    Product
    ProductTable
    ProductType
    ProductTypeTable
```

Product is the model, has variables corresponding to the “products" table fields.

ProductTable is table class which is connected to the database via tableGateway. ProductTable has getItem() method to retrieve requested product by “id”.

ProductType is the model, has variables like id, name, description corresponding to the “productTypes" table fields.

ProductTypeTable is table class just like ProductTable.

Each product belongs to a certain ProductType

```
products.productTypeId = productTypes.id
```

is the relation.

In ProductTable->getItem() method, I can simply get productTypeId.
I can use joins to get productTypes.name, productTypes.description, or any field from "productTypes" table.
But I don’t want to do this - instead dealing with new variables in Product entity like productTypeName, productTypeDesc, 
 I’d like to have `Product->getProductType()` and set it to be a ProductType object, so I can get `Product->getProductType() ->getName()` to get product type name.

Simply I’d like to assign a child model as a variable of the parent model.

I can do this in the controller like below:

```
$product = $this->getProductTable()->getItem(7); // id = 7 
$product->setProductType($this->getProductTypeTable()
                    ->getItem($product->getProductTypeId());
```

But I’d like to make it happen in product table class getItem() method. So I don’t have to think about it in every controller, and it is kind of encapsulated.

What is the right way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you have is the [Table Gateway pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) is only really any good at abstracting database access to a a single database table. It does not in anyway allow for the hydration of entities or management of relationships. Object Relationship Mappers (ORM's), such as Doctrine, solve this problem.

If Doctrine, for whatever reason, is inappropriate for your use case an alternative could be implementing the [Data Mapper Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

> The Data Mapper is a layer of software that separates the in-memory objects from the database. Its responsibility is to transfer data between the two and also to isolate them from each other

The data mapper will *use* the table gateway to fetch the required data for each table and construct the `Product` instance, including it's associated `ProductType`. You would then expose the mapper to the controller (rather than the table gateway).

A simple example of a `ProductMapper`.

```
class ProductMapper
{
    // @var  \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway
    protected $productTable;

    protected $productTypeMapper;

    // an 'identity map' of loaded products
    protected $loaded = []; 

    public function __construct(ProductTable $productTable, ProductTypeMapper $productTypeMapper)
    {
        $this->productTable = $productTable;
        $this->productTypeMapper = $productTypeMapper;
    }

    protected function hydrate(Product $product, array $data)
    { 
        $product->setId($data['id']);
        $product->setName($data['name']);
        $product->setFoo($data['foo']);

        if (isset($data['type_id'])) {
            // Load a fully constructed product type from the database
            $type = $this->productTypeMapper->findById($data['type_id']);
            $product->setType($type);
        }

        return $product;
    }

    public function findById($id)
    {
        if (isset($this->loaded[$id])) {
            return $this->loaded[$id];
        }
        // Get the data
        $row = $this->productTable->select(['id' => $id]);

        if (empty($row)) {
            throw new SomeCustomException("No product could be found with id $id");
        }
        // Create and hydrate the product
        $product = $this->hydrate(new Product, $row->current())
        $this->loaded[$id] = $product;

        return $product;
    }

    public function save(array $data);

    public function update($data);

    public function delete($id);
}
```

Comment: this is really good as far as I can follow your detailed description. It is great because I knew there must be a way but I am not 100% familiar with ZF2. I am trying to avoid Doctrine to use native methods - to learn. I am currently not available to test it, but I wanted to thank you for your efforts to explain it this good. i'll give results when I get back to my computer this weekend.

Comment: I made some research about DataMapper and I can see that it is what I need and what I must learn. However I am too much focused on TableGateway - meaning only familiarized with TableGateway pattern in ZF2 so far and I am having hard time to start without proper documentation and nothing I found was about only DataMapper but some little part of another big picture that doesn't help a beginner. Can you refer to a tutorial or some place for a good start that I can follow like a conventional guide? Beside that, what I understand, DataMapper is exactly the answer of my question. Thanks!

Comment: I would highly recommend the book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (PoEAA)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Addison-Wesley-Signature/dp/0321127420) by Martin Fowler. Despite first being published in 2002 and with most examples are in Java, it is still offers very relevant and concise detail on web application design patterns (the Data Mapper pattern being just one of many).

Comment: I'll give it a try - I don't think it will help me for ZF2 too much but looked like a valuable resource to learn a lot about patterns - which I am not very strong. Thank you.

Comment: regarding your sample ProductMapper and my file structure in my question and again your statement "you would expose the mapper in the controller rather than the table gateway": Am I going to kill ProductTable and ProductTypeTable classes and register Mapper classes and use these instead of Table classes? I can sense that I am asking silly question from an ZF2 expert look but I am very used to use Album Tutorial convention to setup table gateways and return as factories in Module.php, and now I am just trying to follow an organized way as much as Album Tutorial. Thanks again.

Comment: God, if only there was a single ZF2 book that I could follow other than all-the-same-basics kind ones!

Comment: Please ignore my last question, I can now see how it was wrong to ask that, I still need table classes to inject into the mappers, so I did that way and successfully built getServiceConfig as well. This time I just didn't use resultSetPrototype since mapper is already doing that in Hydrate. And I created select method in table classes. I got the product object including the producttype object, great! Now a question if you could answer: how to apply fetchAll? Am I still going to be able to inject producttype object into each fetched item and it won't be a performance trouble? Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, I am acting too fast, actually I found out that I really don't need Table classes anymore, only pass the tableGateway, so removed the table classes and I understand I am going to do everything in the Mapper what I did in the Table classes before. The only question left is fetchall and performance concern now. :) Thank you for letting me learn this far. I can see that DataMapping is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, you just have to follow the following 3 steps:

1. Make your `Product->exchangeArray()` function smarter
2. Get all required `ProductType` fields, using a prefix helps for example: `type_`
3. Add `@var ProductType` so you will have proper autocompete (works for me in Eclipse)

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Product\Model\Product;

   class Product {
       public $id;
       ...
       /**
        * @var ProductType
        */
       public $productType;
       ...
       public function exchangeArray( $data ) {
           $this->id = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
           ...
           $productType = new ProductType();
           $typeData = array(
               'id' => $data['type_id'],
               'value' => $data['type_value']
           );
           $productType->exchangeArray( $typeData );
           $this->productType = $productType;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply. However, I am doing this with joins successfully, and that's what I am trying to avoid. I don't want to populate ProductType object, I'd like to create related ProductType object instance by productTypeId field value coming with Product and use it as linked to Product model as object variable. Thank you.